# Trial to food photography

Tags: food-photography

I have just started to digital photography. I thought food photography might be a good idea. You may find the first photo in the following link: https://www.flickr.com/photos/146796549@N04/32108329002/

I would utterly appreciate your feedback. What do you think I need to work on to improve myself? Thanks in advance.

ps: I have photoshopped the background to plain black. I have not touched anything else.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind uploading your photo and editing into your post, rather than link to it on Flickr? If you ever remove it from Flickr, the link will be stale in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because photo critiques are specifically off topic. [Should Photo Critiques be allowed?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/150/should-photo-critiques-be-allowed)

Comment: But see also 
[Can we re-open the door to something a little like photo critique?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/can-we-re-open-the-door-to-something-a-little-like-photo-critique) — we can definitely help you with more than dry technical matters. We just need something more focused.

Comment: PS: I like where you're going and have a lot of things I *could* say about this. But let's have a question that works with this site's structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do you think I need to work on to improve myself?

I think you need to think about what is the message you want to convey to the viewer and whether the elements that you place/leave in the picture emphasize that message or blurry it. For example, what are you trying to say by the dry spaghetti tossed on the table where you serve the food?

This type of photography depends on good composition and good light. So as a next step, you could do some reading on composition (take a look at [The Photographer's Eye](http://amzn.to/2jxmGWJ), for example) and lighting (e.g. [Picture Perfect Lighting](http://amzn.to/2ii7RpR) or better yet [Light Science and Magic](http://amzn.to/2ilYeJT)).

I think your picture is a great start. I hope you have lots of fun learning, trying and showing photography.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I will check the books. May you elaborate further on technical details such as shutter speed, iso etc. ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. If you feel you need more confidence in this area, there are two ways - practice or reading a book like the Understanding Exposure by Peterson (or ideally both).

Answer (score 1):

It feels busy.  There are many things going and I would try a simpler shot.  Perhaps a shot with just the plate and coffee.

Comment: Agree. That's why food stylists get paid to do what they do. The layout is not very pleasing at all, neither is the focus.